# Solr schema and boosting by keywords/tags for item

Tags: search, solr, tags, code-search-engine

When users searches and clicks a result, we store this search keyword in the DB.
What we get is a list of keywords for every item with the number of times item was clicked for that keyword.

In solr schema I have multivalued field "keywords". How can I add that number of clicks for every keyword on every item and than boost so the most clicked items are on/near the top of results for that keyword ?

I use dismax and for the moment the query for "apple" looks someting like this:

```
q=apple
qf=title^0.4 keywords:"apple"^0.5
bf=hits^0.4 rating^0.3
```

So as you can see I boost by "keywords" but the problem is that I don't know which item was most clicked for "apple".

I've tried adding boost parameter to every keyword on initial index import. It didn't help and I'm out of ideas.

Answer (score 0):

How are you maintaining the clicked data ?
How about also maintaining the cumulative clicked data as a single field with the document.
You can easily use this field to boost the documents overall using the dismax boost functions.
A large set of mathematical functions can be used @ http://wiki.apache.org/solr/FunctionQuery#What_is_a_Function.3F

Comment: Item click data is updated once per day. 

Cumulative clicked data won't improve my results because I need click data for every keyword for that item, to be able to get some decent results.

Comment: so when the each item click data is updated, cant you sum up to be the cumulative clicks (sum of individual clicks for each keywords) for the document and use it ?

Comment: I already have click count for every keyword. Click count is the number of clicks to an item for specific keyword. What I don't know how to do: store this data to solr index and boost by click count.

I've found exactly what I need but it's enterprise with yearly subscription :S [Click Scoring Relevance Framework](http://lucidworks.lucidimagination.com/display/LWEUG/Click+Scoring+Relevance+Framework)

Comment: As you already have the count clicks per keyword per document. Can you sum up the counts of all keywords at client side into one field and store this count into your solr index as a new field and use this field to boost the documents using bf and function queries ?

Comment: This won't help me with relevancy much. Your suggestion is good but I need more exact boosting. In this case I only get overall popularity of an item which sadly is not good enough.